# helper method not accessible in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I have the following code in my view:

```
<%= gravatar_for @user %>
```

and the following code in my helper:

```
module UsersHelper
    def gravatar_for(user)
        gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
        gravatar_url = "http://gravatar.com/avatar#{gravatar_id}.png"
        image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.first_name.to_s + user.last_name.to_s, class: gravatar)
    end

end
```

However I'm getting an error: `undefined local variable or method`gravatar' for #<#:0x00000100a1cbf0>`

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a reference, `gravatar`, in the call to `image_tag`.

If you mean to apply a style, use a string, `"gravatar"`. Otherwise you need to make sure the method or value `gravatar` exists/is initialized, and available.

Comment: my intent is to call the method `gravatar_for` in the helpers and get a returned `image_tag`

Comment: @locoboy I understand that. But `gravatar` either needs to be a string, or a function/variable that's been initialized, like I said.